# How to calculate ratio to the rowmean using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, row, mean

I have dataframe with quantitative values for genes in different samples and want to divide each value with the row mean. Followed by log2 of all values. 
This can be done by base R as below, but I can not get it to work using piping.

Example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame("Gene_Symbol" = c("Gene1","Gene2","Gene3","Gene4","Gene5","Gene6","Gene7"), 
             "Sample1" = c(85657.97656,54417.78906,110949.3281,53197.45313,87156.80469,NA,23880.2832), 
             "Sample2" = c(10423.40918,41660.73047,40094.54688,49519.78125,129387.1094,NA,23903.25977), 
             "Sample3" = c(18778.68359,43655.79688,NA,57447.08984,113266.1484,44810.26172,26316.6543), 
             "Sample4" = c(23919.53125,47829.02344,NA,51478.58203,116275.3359,43110.94922,25417.45508), 
             "Sample5" = c(NA,46677.20313,63389.45313,48722.15234,NA,77135.52344,40265.6875), 
             "Sample6" = c(NA,68596.22656,56802.60938,44712.64063,NA,47744.17969,33689.62891), 
             "Sample7" = c(NA,80506.14844,48722.99219,38629.00781,NA,37885,36638.02344))
```

Want to get to log2 of ratios to the rowmean, as this:

```
  Gene_Symbol      Sample1     Sample2     Sample3     Sample4     Sample5     Sample6    Sample7
1       Gene1  1.303863983 -1.73489640 -0.88562768 -0.53653450          NA          NA         NA
2       Gene2 -0.009130358 -0.39452056 -0.32703546 -0.19532236 -0.23049058  0.32492052  0.5558903
3       Gene3  0.793942295 -0.67448070          NA          NA -0.01364391 -0.17192953 -0.3932840
4       Gene4  0.115606000  0.01225376  0.22648263  0.06822114 -0.01117331 -0.13506843 -0.3460666
5       Gene5 -0.355634714  0.21437397  0.02239683  0.06022518          NA          NA         NA
6       Gene6           NA          NA -0.16205178 -0.21782661  0.62151449 -0.07055606 -0.4042542
7       Gene7 -0.329904867 -0.32851744 -0.18974873 -0.23990523  0.42382615  0.16657972  0.2876169
```

Calculate rowMeans with base R

```
rowMeanValues <- rowMeans(df[,2:ncol(df)], na.rm = TRUE)
```

Divide all quant values with rowMeanValues

```
df[,2:ncol(df)] <- sweep(df[,2:ncol(df)],
                                     MARGIN = 1, FUN = "/",
                                     STATS = rowMeanValues)
```

log2 of ratios

```
df[,2:ncol(df)] <- log2(df[,2:ncol(df)])
```

This gives me the table i want above.
How can I do these calculations in dplyr?

Tried this below, but it divided by column mean instead of rowmean

```
df %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Sample')), funs(./mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Grateful for help!
Henrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to calculate the `rowMeans` first and create that as a column and do the `mutate_at` in the next step.  Here, we are using `rowMeans` from `base R` as it is more efficient than `rowwise` or other forms or reshaping to calculate the row wise means

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(Mean = rowMeans(select(., starts_with('Sample')), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(starts_with('Sample')), ~ log2(./Mean)) %>%
   select(-Mean) # removing the Mean column from the dataset
#Gene_Symbol      Sample1     Sample2     Sample3     Sample4     Sample5     Sample6    Sample7
#1       Gene1  1.303863983 -1.73489640 -0.88562768 -0.53653450          NA          NA         NA
#2       Gene2 -0.009130358 -0.39452056 -0.32703546 -0.19532236 -0.23049058  0.32492052  0.5558903
#3       Gene3  0.793942295 -0.67448070          NA          NA -0.01364391 -0.17192953 -0.3932840
#4       Gene4  0.115606000  0.01225376  0.22648263  0.06822114 -0.01117331 -0.13506843 -0.3460666
#5       Gene5 -0.355634714  0.21437397  0.02239683  0.06022518          NA          NA         NA
#6       Gene6           NA          NA -0.16205178 -0.21782661  0.62151449 -0.07055606 -0.4042542
#7       Gene7 -0.329904867 -0.32851744 -0.18974873 -0.23990523  0.42382615  0.16657972  0.2876169
```

Also, the `.` inside the `mutate_at` is the actual column value, so taking the `mean` of `.` would do only column wise mean and not rowwise

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! What does the ~ mean/do?

Comment: @Henrik It is anonymous function (lambda function) in a compact way.  Otherwise, you may need `function(x) log2(x/Mean)`